# How do I find the sorted position/index of a list in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing

For example, I have a list:

```
[12, 1205, 102, 6]
```

I want to get

```
[1, 3, 2, 0]
```

Because this is the position they are supposed to be in if the list is sorted.

How can I achieve this in python?

Comment: Did you try to solve this? Do you have any code that you need help with?

Comment: Can't you just subtract everything by 1?

Comment: I am just looking for a way to finish it in one line, I wish not to use for loop or while loop

Comment: May be I should change an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a double `numpy.argsort`, or self-indexing:

```
l = [12, 1205, 102, 6]

out = np.argsort(np.argsort(l)).to_list()

# or
x = np.argsort(l)
out = x[x]
```

Output: `[1, 3, 2, 0]`

##### older (inefficient) answer

IIUC, you want the sorted rank:

```
sorted_list = sorted(your_list)
[sorted_list.index(x) for x in your_list]
```

Comment: Although this answers the question, this one-liner is incredibly inefficient, you are sorting the list N times (being N the length of the list).

Comment: That's very true, I computed the sorted values outside of the comprehension

Comment: Note that this solution will not work for lists that contain duplicate values.  Also, the sequential search for each element gives it an O(N x  NLogN) time complexity.  But O(N + NlogN) could be achieved.

Comment: @AlainT. yes that's correct, this was not a good approach, I added a better alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of indexes in the order of sorted values using the sorted() function, then use this to set the positions in the resulting list:

```
L = [12, 1205, 102, 6]

P = sorted(range(len(L)),key=L.__getitem__) # positions in sorted order
S = [None]*len(L)                           # resulting list
for p,i in enumerate(P): S[i]=p             # assign position at original indexes 

print(S) # [1, 3, 2, 0]
```

The equivalent solution using numpy could look like this:

```
S = np.zeros(len(L),dtype=np.int)     # prepare resulting array
S[np.argsort(L)] = np.arange(len(L))  # assign positions at indexes
 
print(S) # array([1, 3, 2, 0])
```

Comment: I think this is correct, but I don't see why you have to create the `S` array, instead of just using a list comprehension for clarity

Comment: Because, in order to place `p` values at the appropriate index in S using a comprehension (i.e. appending), I would need to sort P a second time.   I you print `i` and `p`  inside the for loop, you will see that the assignments are not performed in sequential order.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting your list can be done with numpy:

```
numpy.argsort([2, 3, 5, 1, 4])
```

Comment: This is not what OP expected, this gives the indexes to take in order to sort the array.

Comment: Uh ok well sorry then. But could you explain me how is this different? I'm lost and would appreciate learning the difference between argsort and the OP's expectation

Comment: You have the index to take to get the sorted array, OP simply wanted the rank.